# Does 33 have a multiplicative inverse modulo 72

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Does $33$ have a multiplicative inverse modulo $72$? How would I even figure this out?

Comment: Is the gcd of $33$ and $72$ equal to $1$?

Comment: is it sufficient to say $33x \ne 1 mod 72$ because there is no such number that I can let $x$ be that will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that 33 had a multiplicative inverse $x$ modulo 72. Then we would have $33x \equiv 1 \pmod{72}$, or in other words $$33x = 1+72k$$ for some integer $k$. But this would imply
$$1 = 33-72k = 3(11-24k)$$
so that 1 is a multiple of 3, a contradiction.

As others have alluded to, a general necessary and sufficient condition for $m$ to have a multiplicative inverse modulo $n$ is $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Nice explanation. +1

Answer (score 1):

You have $33*24 = 792$, which is divisible by $72$ (it's $72\cdot 11$).  The possiblity of a multiplicative inverse is now sunk.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Think about the prime factorizations and recall that zero divisors cannot have a multiplicative inverse.